# find the sum of the digits of the integer part of the number and the multiplication of the digits of the fractional part of the number

Tags: python

find the sum of the digits of the integer part of the number and the multiplication of the digits of the fractional part of the number.

I can only output the answer to the integer part of the number.

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: Welcome. Kindly follow @CristiFati suggestions. Very important.

Comment: What number or numbers are you working with. Are they in an array/list .... What Python code did you use to output the int part. Also show what you're try to achieve. ||| Inbtw, Python has operators for remainders `%`, `//`. Modulo and floor div

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us what you tried, so i'll give you only some steps and leave the implementation for you to do by yourself.

1. Split the number into integer and fractional parts:
   You can use the built-in `divmod` function. For example, `divmod(7.86, 1)` returns `(7, 0.86)`.
2. Find the sum of the digits of the integer part. This can be done in multiple ways with varying performance.You can convert the integer part to a string, then iterate over the characters of the string and add the values to a variable.
3. Similarly, you can convert the fractional part to a string after the decimal point, then iterate over the characters of the string and multiply the values with a variable.
4. Return the two results of the steps above.

**Edit:** The code you posted in the comment can be fixed as follows. You want to escape the iteration when hitting the `.` symbol, and make the check first because the user might enter `.456`.

```
s = input() 
letsGo = summa = 0
proizved = 1
for i in s:
    if i == ".":
        letsGo = 1
        continue
    if letsGo == 1:
        proizved *= int(i)
    else:
        summa += int(i)
```

Comment: n = input()
s = str(n)
letsGo = 0
proizved = 1
summa = 0
for i in s:
    if letsGo == 1:
        proizved *= int(i)
    if i == ".":
        letsGo = 1
    if letsGo == 0:
        summa += int(i)
print("Summ: ",summa)
print("Mult: ",proizved)